# C SSL Proxy "Sniffer"/ Decryptor

Tags: c, ssl, proxy, sniffer

I would like to re-program in C the program Burp (https://portswigger.net/burp), at least the part with the proxy.

Burp starts on the computer a proxy over which then the clients in the network "log in" or "access" can.
A CA certificate from Burp will be installed on the clients.
From now on Burp can also read HTTPS traffic.

I would like to re-program this principle in C.

I do not know which libraries to use for
- the proxy
- decrypting the data with de certificate key

Comment: This question is way to broad. It even shows a missing understanding of how Burp and similar work  - these do not decrypt the data with the certificates key but do an active man in the middle "attack" with independent TLS connections on each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people already wrote a proxy in C (for example, nginx).

You can often look through their C code and discover what they did and which libraries they used.

As for the network layer, I am biased since I'm the author of [facil.io](http://facil.io), which I love... But a quick search will offer [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) and [libevent](http://libevent.org) as very common choices that support more platforms (such as Windows).

Comment: With facil.io, libev, libuv and libevent i dont can "decrypt" the data

Comment: All of the libraries support TLS/SSL one way of another. Some of them have integration with OpenSSL or other libraries while others (such as facil.io) offer "hooks" that allow you to attach a TLS/SSL library of your choice (I'm rooting for BearSSL, but it's still considered beta-quality).